# Matlab Parse Binary File

Tags: parsing, matlab, binary

I am looking to speed up the reading of a data file which has been converted from binary (it is my understanding that "binary" can mean a lot of different things - I do not know what type of binary file I have, just that it's a binary file) to plaintext. I looked into reading files quickly awhile ago, and was informed that reading/parsing a binary file is faster than text. So, I would like to parse/read the binary file (that was converted to plaintext) in an effort to speed up the program.

I'm using Matlab for this project (I have a Matlab "program" that needs the data in the file). I guess I need some information on the different "types" of binary, but I really want information on how to read/parse said binary file (I know what I'm looking for in plaintext, so I imagine I'll need to convert that to binary, search the file, then pull the result out into plaintext). The file is a logfile, if that helps in any way.

Thanks.

Comment: Really, this question cannot be answered without knowing the nature of the input and output files, and seeing the code to evaluate what has already been done.

Comment: Does this go back to the "type" of binary file? I'm not familiar with binary files, so I don't understand how something that is "binary" (ones and zeros) can have different "types". Like I said, I don't know all the details on the format of my logfile, but I was hoping to put something together over the weekend that could be modified at work on Monday to match up to the specifics of my logfile.

Comment: No no no, everything is eventually represented `1`s and `0`s, so this statement is too general. A "binary" file means that the data is written in raw form instead of textual ASCII form. For instance, the number `28` would be written in the file as, say, 1 byte, with a value of `0x1C` (which equals 28), instead of two bytes containing the ASCII value of the characters `2` and `8`, i.e. `0x32 0x38`. Is this clear to you?

Comment: I understand that all files are actually binary. I know that if I try and open a binary file with, say, Notepad++, it just looks like garbage. But I don't want to make the binary file readable by myself, I want my computer program (in Matlab) to parse through and find certain things (keywords, etc.), then extract the appropriate information and convert it to plaintext for use by the program. So, I may be looking for the phrase "Case 1", in binary (whatever that may be), then extract the information for case 1.

Comment: Okay. So how do you parse the file? If you want to speed up your code, you have to show post it first for others to see.

Comment: I was working on a different project a couple years ago that involved searching through a file (database), and while doing research for that, came across some information that indicated searching through a binary file would be faster than searching a plaintext file. Honestly, I haven't looked at the current code (someone else wrote it), but I have looked at the plaintext data files, and they consist of lines of data which the program looks through for specific phrases (such as "Case 1"). I can try back Monday with more info, if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in what you are asking -- however, you need to know the format of the file you are reading.  If you can say "At position xx, I can expect to find data yy", that's what you need to know.  In you question/comments you talk about searching for strings.  You can also do it (much like a text file) "when I find xxxx in the file, give me the following data up to nth character, or up to the next yyyy".

You want to look at the documentation for `fread`.  In the documentation there are snippets of code that will get you started, but as I (and others) said you need to know the format of your binary files.  You can use a hex editor to ascertain some information if you are desperate, but what should be quicker is the documentation for the program that outputs these files.

Regarding different "binary files", well, there is least significant byte first or LSB last.  You really don't need to know about that for this work.  There are also other platform-dependent issues which I am almost certain you don't need to know about (unless you are moving the binary files from Mac to PC to unix machines).  If you read to almost the bottom of the `fread` documentation, there is a section entitled "Reading Files Created on Other Systems" which talks about the issues and how to deal with them.

Another comment that I have to make, you say that "reading/parsing a binary file is faster than text".  This is not true (or even if it is, odds are you won't notice the performance gain).  In terms of development time, however, reading/parsing a textfile will save you huge amounts of time.

Comment: Thank you! Not quite what I was looking for (in terms of not being faster), but still much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to store data in a binary file is to use the 'save' command.
If you load from a saved variable it should be significantly faster than if you load from a text file.

Comment: I already have the binary file (well, it's at work). If I have to talk to someone on Monday about how the binary file is generated, I will, but I was hoping to try and develop some code this weekend to have a starting point on Monday.